# Adding string attributes to dynamic labels

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to set the colour of a static part of the text in a `UILabel` while the dynamic part turns into the highscore. There seems to be conflict between the statement that sets the colour and the statement that sets the highscore.

These lines in `viewDidLoad()` make the "Highscore" part green.

```
var myString:NSString = "Highscore\n0"  
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()

myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!])
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:9)) 
labelHighscore.attributedText = myMutableString
```

While this line in another method formats the label to update the score (the 0 part) but doesn't keep the green.

```
labelHighscore.text = NSString(format: “Highscore\n%i", Highscore) as String
```

Calling `viewDidLoad()` after this line allows "Highscore" to stay green but then the score doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
let highScore = 209

let myString = NSString(format: "Highscore\n%i", highScore)

var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!])
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:9))
```

Works perfectly fine for me, I'm not sure what you mean by "both" above.

if you call some code like: `label.text = "Highscore\n0"` this will override the attributed string, so anytime that you update the value of highScore, you'd need to set the attributed string again. there is a few ways you can make this easier, for example you could create a function that takes a score and returns the attributed, formed string. like this:

```
func getAttributedString(score:Int) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let myString = NSString(format: "Highscore\n%i", score)
    let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!])
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:9))

    return myMutableString
}
```

and then in viewDidLoad you can set it's default value:

```
labelHighscore.attributedText = getAttributedString(0)
```

and then whenever the score is updated, you can update the label:

```
let newScore = currentScore + 50
labelHighscore.attributedText = getAttributedString(newScore)
```

You could even get the function to set the attributed text of the label for you

```
func updateScoreLabel(score:Int) -> Void {
    let myString = NSString(format: "Highscore\n%i", score)
    let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!])
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:9))

    labelHighscore.attributedText = myMutableString
}
```

**EDIT:**

I don't think you can just set the attributed text and then keep updating it and keep the formatting (I could be wrong here), I think that when you need to update the text you have to set the attribtedText value each time, I done a quick test app with a label and a button, the button adds 100 to the score each time. When I tried .text = "Highscore: (highScore)" the formatting was lost, code example below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var highScore = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        updateScoreLabel()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        highScore += 100
        updateScoreLabel()
    }

    func updateScoreLabel() -> Void {

        let myString = NSString(format: "Highscore\n%i", highScore)
        let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!])
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:9))

        label.attributedText = myMutableString
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have clarified my question if it helps.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer with how I done it in a test project.